# How to get final version of a completely deleted paragraph Word VBA

Tags: vba, ms-word

For each paragraph with at least one revision, I want to show in an Excel file 3 columns.

- ORIGINAL: column with the original text of the paragraph, no markup.
- MODIFIED: column with the text and all the markup.
- REVISED: column with the final text of the paragraph, no markup.

I managed to find the first 2 column correctly, for the final version all fine unless a paragraph has been completely deleted.
In this case, the final text is the text of the next paragraph.

Below the snippet that works for all other cases.

Any idea?

```
With ActiveWindow.View
    .ShowRevisionsAndComments = False
    
    .RevisionsView = wdRevisionsViewOriginal
    If par.Range.ListFormat.ListType <> 0 Then
        originalText = par.Range.ListFormat.ListString & "    " & IIf(par.Range.Words.count > 0, par.Range.Text, "")
    Else
        originalText = IIf(par.Range.Words.count > 0, par.Range.Text, "")
    End If
    
    .RevisionsView = wdRevisionsViewFinal
    If par.Range.ListFormat.ListType <> 0 Then
        revisedText = par.Range.ListFormat.ListString & "    " & IIf(par.Range.Words.count > 0, par.Range.Text, "")
    Else
        revisedText = IIf(par.Range.Words.count > 0, par.Range.Text, "")
    End If
    
    .ShowRevisionsAndComments = True
End With
```